# eureka property to display datacenter and environment in the Eureka dashboard

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am working with the latest `2020.0.3` version of Spring cloud Eureka server. Which property in the application configuration will display the datacenter and environment in the Eureka dashboard? It is not clear in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in AWS you'll need this bean.

```
@Bean @Primary
@Profile("aws")
public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils) {
    EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
    AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
    config.setDataCenterInfo(info);
    return config;
}
```

more info -> https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_using_eureka_on_aws